# Yeoman generator-webapp running on HTTPS

Tags: https, gruntjs, yeoman

Can someone guide me how to configure generator-webapp to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Tried https option and specified key files but somehow I made something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself. All that needs to be done was to add https. The rest will be handled by browserSync. It also assigns a self-signed certificate.

`browserSync: {
            options: {
                notify: false,
                background: true,
                watchOptions: {
                    ignored: ''
                },
                https: {
                    key: '',
                    cert: ''
                }
            },`